# Get a specific attribute from an object React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an object which I got from an API call. I have passed the object through `route.params`
I want to take `warrantyStatus` from the `tasks` array for specific `serialNumber` which I got from `route.params`.
I pass the `serialNumber` through `route.params` as `PSerial`
following is my Object

```
      "tasks": Array [
        Object {
          "completed": false,
          "createdAt": null,
          "model": "Lexmark:T650N",
          "product": "Printer",
          "remark": "POWER SUPPLY UNIT NOT WORKING",
          "serialNumber": "794DCYL",
          "status": null,
          "topic": "21081235T69",
          "ttId": 27945,
          "warrantyStatus": "MAINTENANCE_COMPREHENSIVE",
        }, ]
```

I have taken the `serialNumber` as `PSerial` from `route.params`. So I want to take out the `warrantyStatus` and show in a `Text` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your `tasks` array based on `PSerial` and the `warrantyStatus` property.

Simply find the item with,

```js
const item = tasks.find(item => item.serialNumber === PSerial)
```

Now the item will have the corresponding matching object. You can access the `warrantyStatus` by `item.warrantyStatus` and show it in a `Text` component.

You can use the array `filter` function if you are expecting multiple tasks to have the same `warrantyStatus` property.

```js
const items = tasks.filter(item => item.serialNumber === PSerial)
```

The items now will be an array having all tasks matching the provided `PSerial` value.

Comment: i added it but it shows me as `iitem : Array []` & console log.
    `const item = dataOBJ.tasks.filter(item => item.warrantyStatus === PSerial)
    console.log("iitem :",item)`

Comment: that means no items match with the given `PSerial` value, hence empty array as result

Comment: I added this `dataOBJ.tasks.find(item => item.warrantyStatus === PSerial)` is it ok beacuse you have missed the `dataOBJ.tasks` at the answer

Comment: `const item = (dataOBJ.tasks)
    console.log("iitem :",item)`
this was the console.log

`iitem : Array [
  Object {
    "completed": false,
    "createdAt": null,
    "model": "Lexmark:MS510DN",
    "product": "PRINTER",
    "remark": "paper jam",
    "serialNumber": "451444HH1N1GT",
    "status": null,
    "topic": "21080295T210",
    "ttId": 27226,
    "warrantyStatus": "MAINTENANCE_COMPREHENSIVE",
  },
]`

Comment: `PSerial` = `serialNumber` in the array. `Tasks Array` has multiple Objects. can you look in to that

Comment: Oopsie...sorry my mistake, the check should be `item.serialNumber === PSerial`. IDK how the other thing came into my mind.. If you use `filter` method with this condition, it will return an array of objects with `serialNumber` equal to the passed `PSerial`

Comment: and ` dataOBJ.tasks.` is fine as `tasks` is a property of the `datOBJ` value.